# render HTML dynamically in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular 2 app in which I had created a dialog which will popup on user click. And the content in that dialog has to be dynamically rendered as html. Static html is running well but dynamic is not running.

Code:

```
<md-dialog-content><h1>Hello Angular 2</h1></md-dialog-content>////It works..

<md-dialog-content>{{test}}</md-dialog-content>///It does not work.
```

It displays the text as `'<h1>Hello Angular 2</h1>'`

In Component:

```
let test = "<h1>Hello Angular 2</h1>";
```

Comment: `let = "<h1>Hello Angular 2</h1>";` ?? you have to declare name with `let`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply use `[innerHTML]` directive to achieve it.

```
<md-dialog-content>
    <span [innerHtml]='test'></span>
</md-dialog-content>
```

Comment: I want to add an href indise innerHtml. How can I do it?

Comment: simply use `a` instead of `span` then, is there any issue with this ? and change href with `routerLink`

Comment: @PardeepJain can i use innerHtml with a UI framework like Ant Design  ? E.g : test='<nz-table>...</nz-table>'